# Why does this char not show the default char methods in the IDE?

Tags: c#

I am developing in Visual Studio 08 in the C# language, I am trying to loop over each `char` in a `String` after it has been converted to a `char[]`. The problem is that the IDE/C# does not acknowledge that my `char` is really a `char`, this picture explain it a little better.

[image]

As you can see on the left, the variable `aChar` which is of type `char` (presumably) does not show the same methods as what `char.` does on the right. Is there anything noticeably wrong with how I am trying to loop over the `chars` in the `searchString`?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx). The methods marked with an `S` are static and will be visible from the `char` struct name, but not from an instance of `char`. The one's without the `S` are visible from an instance of `char` but not the struct name itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods you see with `char.` are static methods and available with type name like `char.ConvertFromUtf32`.

Your variable `aChar` will only show instance methods.

As a side note: You don't have to call `ToCharArray` in `foreach`

```
foreach(char aChar in searchString)
```

is enough

Comment: Ahhh... Wow, sometimes I surprise myself. `char.IsLetter(aChar)` is how to do it.

Comment: @AnotherUser, you also don't have to call `ToCharArray` in foreach, `foreach(char aChar in searchString)` is enough

Comment: Splitting hairs, but `char` is a struct not a class.

Comment: @MattBurland, yes :) type name should have been there instead of class name

Comment: @Habib just wave your hands and say "I was talking about the IL; at the IL level, char is a class"

Answer (score 0):

On the left, all methods are instance methods (for your `aChar` variable). On the right, the methods you see are class (`char`) static methods.

Answer (score 0):

On the left, you are looking at member variables only since you're doing a dot operator on an instance of char. On the right, you're looking at static methods, since you're using the dot operator on a class.